# How to transform data type when trying to find a match using Google Sheets query language

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to query for a specific row in a sheet by its content using this query in javascript:

```
const query = `SELECT * WHERE ${idColumn} = '${id}'`;
```

The problem is, sometimes the column seems to be a string, and sometimes it seems to be a number.
When a number, I would have to remove the single quotes from the id `${idColumn} = ${id}`

The problem is that I don't know when the column is going to be a string or number,
I was hoping I could transform the data to string first.
Is that possible?

Something like:

```
const query = `SELECT * WHERE TO_TEXT(${jobIdColumn}) = '${jobId}'`
```

EDIT:
Here is an example file where column A is considered numbers by Google sheet, and column B is considered String:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HYEuPr_1xqeCqL29ekuoSv1lZuVgfDUxpc8c1ZMYjUA/edit#gid=0

I can't use the same formula, to query both Columns,
I have to use single quotes on column B but none in column A

```
=QUERY(A1:B7,"SELECT A WHERE A = 5555    ",-1)
=QUERY(A1:B7,"SELECT A WHERE B = 'C5555' ",-1)
```

My Workaround right now is to use `OR`, but that doesn't seem right

`SELECT * WHERE ${idColumn} = '${id}' OR ${idColumn} = ${id}`

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const query = `SELECT * WHERE ${idColumn} = '${id}'`;
```

#### To:

```
const query = `SELECT * WHERE ${idColumn} = ${isNaN(id) ? `'${id}'` : Number(id)}`;
```

- By this modification, when `id` is a string, the value is enclosed by the single quotes. When `id` is a number, the value is not enclosed.
- In this case, it supposes that `id` is not null. Please be careful about this.

#### Testing:

```js
const idColumn = "A";
["sample", 123].forEach(id => {
  const query = `SELECT * WHERE ${idColumn} = ${isNaN(id) ? `'${id}'` : Number(id)}`;
  console.log(query);
});
```

Comment: Sorry about that. The id from my code, It's always going to be a string, what I can't tell is the data type of the id field inside the google sheets.
If I add quotes to the query `SELECT * WHERE A = '5555'` it will only return the rows if Colum A has the text 555 and the data type for that field is a text. 
If the data type is a number even though visually I can see the 5555 inside the row, it won't match. I updated the question with a Spreadsheet with more info

Comment: @Allan Thank you for replying. About `If I add quotes to the query SELECT * WHERE A = '5555' it will only return the rows if Colum A has the text 555 and the data type for that field is a text.`, in my proposed script, when `id` is a string like `'5555'`, `SELECT * WHERE A = 5555` is returned. How about this?

Comment: @Allan About your updated question, first, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your column "A" and column "B". What is your expected result of your updated question? For example, if you want to retrieve row 6 by columns "A" and "B", how about `SELECT * WHERE A = 5555 AND B = 'C5555'"`? If you want to use a script, how about `SELECT * WHERE A = ${id} AND B = 'C${id}'` with `id = 5555`? If I misunderstood your updated question, I apologize.